# Count words in a file?

Tags: c, file

I have a program written in C which should count the number of times the word "the" appears in text files that are given as arguments.But the program keeps giving a segmentation fault error and I have no more ideas on how to solve this.Any help would be appreciated.Thank you!

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ 
  int h,i;
  FILE *fp;
  char* mess;
  for(i=1; i < argc; i++)
  { 
     h=0;
     fp=fopen(argv[i],"r");
      while (!feof(fp))
      { 
        fscanf(fp,"%s",mess);
        if (strcmp(mess,"the")==0)
          h++;
      }
      printf("The file %s contains the word \"the\" %d times.",argv[i],h);
      h=0; 
      fclose(fp);
  }
}
```

Comment: May I add that C is overkill for this kind of job? "main = interact $ show . length . filter (=="the") . words" is enough.

Comment: @IGCA, it's presumably an assignment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 char* mess;
 [...]
       fscanf(fp,"%s",mess);
```

mess is uninitialised. You need to allocate some space for the word you are reading in

> s     Matches a sequence of
>   non-white-space characters; the next
>   pointer must be a pointer to char, and
>   the array must be large enough to
>   accept all the sequence and the
>   terminating NUL character.  The input
>   string stops at white space or at the
>   maximum field width, whichever occurs
>   first.

so you also want to use the field width to limit what you read to the size of your buffer. This requires a bit of careful handling since the bit after your buffer size just might be "the" (e.g. "breathe", if you read 4 character words, would give you "brea" and "the" and a false positive)

Answer (score 1):

The `char* mess` is an unitialized pointer. In other words : it is a variable whose value is a random address in memory. In your call to `fscanf` an attempt will be made to write something at this address and your program will crash.

Either make `mess` an array of fixed size or make it point to a valid memory block which has been dynamically allocated using `malloc` (which is probably useless here). In both cases, you'll probably want to make sure that you cannot read more than `size` character or you'll end up with a whole new segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

`fscanf(fp,"%s",mess);` won't allocate memory!

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate memory for the buffer `mess` being given to `sscanf`:

`char mess[256];`

Currently, `mess` is uninitialized (null).  `sscanf` trips over trying to write to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (!feof(fp))
{ 
  fscanf(fp,"%s",mess);
  if (strcmp(mess,"the")==0)
  h++;
}
```

You're reading a string from a file, putting it into `mess`, which is a plain pointer to a char. You need character array:

```
char mess[1000];
```

Comment: A "plain pointer to a char" would be fine if some memory was allocated for it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can read from the code, you have not initialized the `mess` pointer before you used it to be populated by the fscanf:

```
fscanf(fp,"%s",mess);
```

Answer (score 0):

allocate memory for mess using either `mess=malloc(sizeof(char)*SOME_NUMBER)` or simply declaring mess as array of characters i.e char mess[1024];